# AVAudioPlayer freezes when play first song

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I'm using AVAudioPlayer class to play sound in my app. When i play sound first time, screen freezes for a 2-3 seconds, then it becomes active and without freezes and delays. Even when I change sound. Here is some code:

```
avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
```

Sound files are in Documents folder and file paths are correct; How to minimize delay or remove freezes?

Comment: How big are these sound files?  I have used AVAudioPlayer extensively, with different sound files, and have never experienced this.  I am curious if the files are very large, or whether you see this issue on other devices too.  (and while not a problem, calling -prepareToPlay isn't necessary here since -play will call it too)

Comment: Freeze comes only for first sound. File sizes are different. Between 5-11 MBytes. If i play video before playing sound, everything works without freeze.

Comment: I have file sizes much bigger than that.  Can you repeat this behavior on other devices?  Does it occur in the Simulator?

Comment: Yes, it occurs in the simulator, i will test on real device when i will have apple developer account

Comment: So this issue only occurs on the Simulator?  It could be your Mac that is causing the delay.

Comment: I've not tested on real device yet. I'm waiting for developer program account activation

Comment: I have this issue in 2017, iOS 11, both simulator and a real device.